# looping logistic regression in R

Tags: loops, apply, logistic-regression

I have been trying to run logistic regression looping all columns in raw file (predictors) with binary outcome (outcome.csv file).

```
raw <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=500, ncol=10))
out <- read.csv(file="outcome.csv", header=T)

models <- list()
res <- list()
a <- colnames(raw)
for(i in 1:length(raw){ 
models[[i]] <- summary(glm(out$blue ~ raw[,i] + out$sex, data=raw , family= binomial ) )
res[[i]] <- paste("logistic", a[[i]], ".txt", sep="")
write.table(models, res, row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, sep="\t")
}
```

it kept saying this

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = out$blue ~ raw[, i] + out$MALE,  :
  variable lengths differ (found for 'raw[, i]')
```

Any suggestions related for loop or apply would be very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: How many rows are in outcome.csv? This needs to be the same length as raw (which according to your question doesnt contain any data anyway so maybe not the best predictor).